# Flask session doesn't work in anoter url apart from the url of the flask app

Tags: reactjs, flask, session-cookies

I have Flask app and React app.
I have session at the flask app.
I want the flask session to be also in my React app.
This is a part of the flask app

```
@views.route("/login/<email>/<password>")
def log(email,password):
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if user:
        if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            session.permanent = True
            session["user"] = email
            infor_user = user
            user_infor = {"name": infor_user.username, "email": infor_user.email}
            return jsonify({"success": user_infor})
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "Password is incorrect"})
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "User doesn't exist"})


@views.route("/checkuser")
def check_user():
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        infor_user = User.query.filter_by(email=user).first()
        user_infor = {"name": infor_user.username, "email": infor_user.email}
        return jsonify({"user": user_infor})
    else:
        return jsonify({"user": {}})

@views.route("/out")
def out():
    session.pop("user",None)
    return jsonify{"message": "logged out"}"
```

and This is the React app.

```
import {useContext,useState} from "react"
import {username} from "./username"



function Login(){

const [infor,setInfor] = useContext(username)
const [inusername, setInusername] = useState("")
const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
const [error, setError] = useState("")

if(infor){
    return (
        <div>You are already Logged in!!!</div>
    )
}

const checkLogin = () => {

    if(!inusername || !password){
        setError("Those parts need to be writen")
    }
    else{
        console.log(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/log/${inusername}/${password}`)
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/log/${inusername}/${password}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) =>  {
        if ("error" in data){
            setError(data["error"])
        }

        else{
           setInfor(data["seccess"])
        }
    });
    }    
    }


return(
    <div>
        <p>{error ? error : ""}</p>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInusername(e.target.value)}/>
        <input type="password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={checkLogin}>Login!</button>
    </div>
)
    
}

export default Login
```

I tried to make the session be at the React app, but from some reason it always says to me that the session doesn't exist.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "session"? If you are talking about the cookie, then it is probably because the cookie is http-only meaning the client JS can't access it. And even if you change that, the session cookie is supposed to be "encrypted" so that only the server can read and modify it, and clients won't temper with it.

Comment: Maybe it's http-only, so if it's http-only how can I fix it?